# INNER JOIN to view detail another table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Well, I have the following table (Table1):

```
------------------------------------
GroupID      oDate          oDesc
------------------------------------
1            2016-05-01     A
2            2016-05-20     B
3            2017-03-01     C
4            2017-03-28     D
```

Then I have the following table (Table2):

```
------------------------------------
AutoID      GroupID        oItem
------------------------------------
1           1              abc
2           1              def
3           2              ghi
4           2              jkl
5           3              mno
6           4              pql
```

I want to know all `oItem` in Table2 that has a link to Table1 in a same year. The result should be like this:

```
---------------------------
oYear       oItem
---------------------------
2016        abc
2016        def
2016        ghi
2016        jkl
2017        mno
2017        pql
```

Is there any idea how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Is `oItem` unique or can it repeat? If it isn't unique, and repeats more than once per year, do you want to see it *once* in the output, or multiple times?

Comment: no, it isn't. could be repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `inner join` to get the desired result.

```
select datepart(yyyy, t1.odate) as oyear, t2.oitem
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.groupid = t2.groupid
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Year`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms186313.aspx) inbuilt function to *extract* year from date column. Try this

```
select Year(Odate) as Oyear,B.oItem
from table1 A inner join table2 B
on A.GroupID = B.GroupID
```